# gai_cancel() takes a really long time to succeed

Tags: c++, linux, dns, getaddrinfo, getaddrinfo-a

I am trying to look up domain asynchronously in c++. The reason is I want to be able to effectively add a time out period in case the system can't look up the domain. I came across the getaddrinfo_a() command so I decided to give it a try. However cancelling any dns look up that will not succeed (such as when there is no internet connection) will never take less than 20 seconds on my machine. Here is a simple example of this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {


        int ret;
        gaicb* reqs;

        reqs = new gaicb;

        memset(reqs, 0, sizeof (gaicb));
        reqs->ar_name = "google.com";

        ret = getaddrinfo_a(GAI_NOWAIT, &reqs, 1, NULL);
        if (ret != 0) {
                cout << "something went wrong" << endl;
                return false;
        }

        while (1) {
                ret = gai_cancel(reqs);
                if (ret == EAI_CANCELED || ret == EAI_ALLDONE) {
                        break;
                }
                usleep(100 * 1000); //sleep for 100 milliseconds
        }

        cout << "finished cancellation" << endl;


        return 0;
}
```

Compile like this:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -lanl
```

Then run the command on your linux based system without an internet connection like so:

```
time ./main
```

You will find that the program always takes about 20 seconds to close. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `gai_cancel` manpage states: "the request cannot be canceled if it is currently being processed; in that case, it will be handled as if gai_cancel() has never been called."

Comment: @Andrey Akhmetov Right but what is the point of having an asynchronous dns look up call if it cannot be cancelled for at least 20 seconds? Doesn't seem asynchronous at all. Or at the very minimum defeats the purpose of allowing a process to be asynchronous.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough insight on the internals of this function amd related ones  to tell you *why* this might be, only that it's documented as being so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the answer is to not use getaddrinfo_a(3) if you need asynchronous dns lookup shorter than 20 seconds. Also per Martin Sustrik's second comment on http://sourceware-org.1504.n7.nabble.com/getaddrinfo-a-memory-leaks-td233794.html as well as my experience here it looks like getaddrinfo_a is fairly experimental and shouldn't be used anyways. I actually ended up using dns.c (https://github.com/wahern/dns). Here's a sample for anyone looking:

```
#include "dns.c"

uint8_t getaddrinfo_k(
uint32_t* ip_addr, const char* dns_address, uint32_t timeout) {
    int32_t                 rc;
    struct addrinfo         hints;
    struct dns_resolv_conf* dns_conf;
    struct dns_hosts*       dns_hosts;
    struct dns_hints*       dns_hints;
    struct dns_resolver*    resolver;
    struct dns_addrinfo*    ai;
    struct addrinfo*        it;

    dns_conf    = dns_resconf_local(&rc);
    assert(dns_conf);
    dns_hosts   = dns_hosts_local(&rc);
    assert(dns_hosts);
    dns_hints   = dns_hints_local(dns_conf, &rc);
    assert(dns_hints);
    resolver    = dns_res_open(
    dns_conf, dns_hosts, dns_hints, NULL, dns_opts(), &rc);
    assert(resolver);
    it          = NULL;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = PF_INET;

    ai = dns_ai_open(dns_address, "80", DNS_T_A, &hints, resolver, &rc);
    assert(ai);

    while (timeout-- > 0) {
        rc = dns_ai_nextent(&it, ai);
        switch(rc) {
                case 0:
                        *ip_addr = (
                        (struct sockaddr_in *) it->ai_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr;
                        free(it);
                        goto exit_loop;
                case EAGAIN:
                        rc = dns_ai_poll(ai, 1);
                        assert(rc == 0);
                        break;
                default:
                        goto exit_loop;
        }
        usleep(100 * 1000);
    }

    exit_loop:

    dns_ai_close        (ai);
    dns_res_close       (resolver);
    dns_hints_close     (dns_hints);
    dns_hosts_close     (dns_hosts);
    dns_resconf_close   (dns_conf);

    switch(rc) {
        case 0:
            return 1;
        case EAGAIN:
            printf("DNS_WRAPPER: timed out\n");
            break;
        case ENOENT:
            printf("DNS_WRAPPER: file doesn't exist\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("DNS_WRAPPER: unknown error\n");
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the first hint, on how to use the dns.c lib, that I've seen. It's meant to self explanatory, I think. But when you read the header, there's 1 million functions and no usage information. And all you really want, is a non blocking getaddrinfo. ;)